# Calling Microsoft Graph API using Postman

Tags: ruby, postman, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, bearer-token

I automate tests and I need to send a report to my squad. The company uses Microsoft tools (Outlook, Teams, etc.)

I'm trying to send a message in a chat using the Microsoft Graph API and Postman before I code it.

When I'm using the Graph Explorer, I can access the data that I need. But when I'm doing using Postman, my access token validation fail.

It's possible to call Microsoft Graph API using Postman? Where I get the right Bearer Authorization (I'm getting the Bearer token in a Microsoft Teams Login)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to call Graph api from postman. You would need to get the access token with suitable permissions required to call your graph api. Please go through [Get access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0) to get the appropriate token and make a call. Please let me know if you need any further help.